# How to prevent vertical scroll bar to lap my stack panels wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, stack, panel, stackpanel

I am wondering how could I prevent vertical scroll bar from lapping my stack panels.

I am working on small wpf app where customers can add articles(drinks) to a something like cart, and when user click on article its added to the right part of window in stack panel, this is how it looks a like:

[image]

But I have problem when I add more than lets say 5-6 items to my stack panel, than vertical scroll bar is appearing and this is what's happening (notice vertical scroll bar to the right) its laping "x1":

[image]

How could I prevent this guy? Is it possible to move content to the left or something like that without laping my items/articles ...

If the code of how I add items to stackPanel is needed, I will post it in a sec?

HERE IS MY FULL CODE ABOUT THIS PART:

```
  public MyDrinksPanel(int id, int groupID, double price,double priceHappy, string text, int fontSize, int numberSize, int buttonWidth, int buttonHeight, int margin, Thickness border, byte[] image)
            : base()
        {
            this.Width = buttonWidth+90;
            this.Height = buttonHeight;
            image.Source =  GetimageFromByte(image);

            ID = id;
            groupID = groupID;
            price = price;
            priceHappy = priceHappy;
            DugmePanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            DugmePanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            DugmePanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            DugmePanel.MaxWidth = DugmePanel.Width = buttonWidth;
            //DugmePanel.Height = 70;
            DugmePanel.Height = DugmePanel.MaxHeight = this.Height;
            BrushConverter MyBrush = new BrushConverter();

            DugmePanel.Background = (Brush)MyBrush.ConvertFrom("#50000000");



            _image.Width = 120;

            _image.Height = buttonHeight;
            _image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            _image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;


            BrushConverter MyBrush2 = new BrushConverter();



            RightNumberPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            RightNumberPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            RightNumberPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            RightNumberPanel.Width = RightNumberPanel.MaxWidth = this.Width - DugmePanel.Width;
            RightNumberPanel.Height = RightNumberPanel.MaxHeight = this.Height;
            NumberLabel.FontFamily = Util.Font; //new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf#Helvetica Neue LT Std");


            ArticleNameLabel.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            ArticleNameLabel.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            ArticleNameLabel.FontSize = fontSize;

            ArticleNameLabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;

            ArticleNameLabel.MaxWidth = _image.Width+45; //- 3;
            ArticleNameLabel.FontFamily = Util.Font;//new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf#Helvetica Neue LT Std");



            NumberLabel.Height = NumberLabel.MaxHeight = this.Height;
            NumberLabel.FontSize = numberSize;
            NumberLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            NumberLabel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            NumberLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            NumberLabel.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            NumberLabel.Foreground= System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
            NumberLabel.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            BrushConverter MyBrush3 = new BrushConverter();

            NumberLabel.Background = (Brush)MyBrush3.ConvertFrom("#83D744");
            NumberLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);



            ArticleNameLabel.Content = text;
            NumberLabel.Content = "x1";

            DugmePanel.Children.Add(image);
            DugmePanel.Children.Add(ArticleNameLabel);
            RightNumberPanel.Children.Add(NumberLabel);

            Rectangle rct = new Rectangle();
            rct.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
            rct.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            rct.Height = 2;


            //rct.Width = 100;

            _animations = new DoubleAnimation(numberSize, numberSize + 15, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300)));

            _animations.AutoReverse = true;

            this.Margin = border;
            this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            StackPanel spNew = new StackPanel();
            spNew.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            spNew.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;

            spNew.Children.Add(DugmePanel);
            spNew.Children.Add(RightNumberPanel);
            StackPanel spNew2 = new StackPanel();
            spNew2.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;

            spNew2.Children.Add(spNew);

            this.Children.Add(spNew2);

        }
```

I dont have a lot about XAML HERE:
This is only part:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollerOnTheRight" Margin="0,0,0,60" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="stackRacun" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: Do your list items (or their content, etc.) have a fixed width, or does everything stretch to fill its parent? If you show us the XAML we can come up with a better guess about what's wrong with it.

Comment: Show the XAML......

Comment: @Ed Plunkett I made edit, there is full code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I made edit, there is full code..

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense of that. You should use XAML.

Comment: @Ed plunkett well by that, we can see that this is made from 2 stack panels, one contains image and name, and another one(right one) contains only quantity, x1,x2 etc.. and their width is fixed, because its passed to pathod which is creating this panels.. so its problem, to keep stack panels fixed?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Don't fix the width. Maybe do a Grid with two columns, Width=Auto and Width=*.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Than I should work with XAML more than with code behind and we might achieve someting like that..

Comment: It's much, much less awful to do it with XAML. Still awful, granted.